# EF 6, .NET 4.8 : resulting query doesn't seem to use StringLength

Tags: entity-framework-6, string-length, .net-4.8, ef-fluent-api

I've seen similar questions and have tried applying the answers, but to no avail, so I wanted to ask my question with more context of what I've tried.

My property looks like this:

```
[Column("colnm")], TypeName ="varchar")]
[StringLength(4)]
public string ColumnName { get; set; }
```

The resulting select query becomes this:

```
@p__linq__0 varchar(8000)
```

I need it to be this:

```
@p__linq__0 varchar(4)
```

When it's 8000, it does a table scan and the query is not performant at all. The column in the database is defined as `varchar(4)`, so I'm trying to tell EF to use `varchar(4)`.

To be clear, we had the tables set up before we needed this entity, and this is not a migration. I'm just trying to get EF to handle a select query on my entity.

I've tried only using `StringLength`, changing it to `MaxLength`, putting it inline with `TypeName("varchar(4)")`, and all of the above in FluentAPI as well in my context. It always stays at `varchar(8000)`.

I know that my entity impacts the query, because when I change `varchar` to `nvarchar`, I see the 8000 drop to 4000. But it never gets down to 4.

I can't find anywhere that's explicitly overriding my `StringLength` either.

Even ChatGPT provided suggestions that made sense, but none of them worked. :)

Ideas?

Comment: When you say "not performant", have you looked at the actual execution plan? The typical string performance penalty is when C#/EF passes strings as NVARCHAR to compare to a VARCHAR column, which your column config is handling. AFAIK parameters don't need to match the length or their column counterparts, so a parameter length 8000 should have no issue with a matching string type length 4 in the database. You may be chasing the wrong culprit behind your performance concerns.